# Dependency injection in functional programming

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection

This problem is better illustrated with an example. I'll use Javascript (actually Coffeescript for syntax sake), but just because Javascript is just another [LISP](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/little.html), right?

So, suppose I'm writing a web app which does (obviously) ajax requests. I implement a function  to handle that:

```
ajaxRequest = (url, params, callback) ->
    # implementation goes here
```

Now, suppose I have a grid that fetches data from the server. Somewhere in my code I must do something like this:

```
userGrid.onMustFetch = ->
    ajaxRequest '/fetch/users', { surname: 'MacGyver' }, (data) ->
        # fill grid with data
```

What exactly is the problem here? If I want to test the implementation of *onMustFetch*, I will not be able to do so, because inside *onMustFetch*, a dependency is being called, and the test environment cannot control the dependency.

To solve this problem, I inject the dependency into the function I want to test. That means changing *onMustFetch* to this:

```
userGrid.onMustFetch = (ajaxRequest) ->
    ajaxRequest '/fetch/users', { surname: 'MacGyver' }, (data) ->
        # fill grid with data
```

Now the test code can pass a mock of *ajaxRequest* to *onMustFetch* and successfully test the behavior.

Wunderbar, right? Wrong! Now I have a second problem, the problem of having to bind the right instance of *ajaxRequest* to the right instance of *onMustFetch*.

In a language like Java, I could use a Dependency Injection framework to do this for me, and my code would look like this:

```
class UserGrid {

    private AjaxService ajaxService;

    @Inject
    public UserGrid(AjaxService ajaxService) {
        this.ajaxService = ajaxService;
    }

    public void onMustFetch() {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("surname", "MacGyver");
        ajaxService.request("/fetch/users", params, new AjaxCallback(data) {
            // fill grid with data
        });
    }

}
```

Creepy, I know... but actually the DI framework does all the wiring, so at least that part of the problem is easier.

Now back to our web app and to Javascript. Even if I successfully manage to always invoke *onMustFetch* with the right *ajaxRequest* reference (after all in this case that is not so hard to do), there must be an easier way. When my code grows, the dependencies increase. I can imagine passing a reference of *ajaxRequest* around, but what about when I have a *securityService*, a *browserService*, a *eventBusService*, etc, etc, etc.?

Now the real question here: How do lisp like languages solve this problem of managing dependencies?
(It seems to me the dependencies must keep being passed around all over the application, but I'm sure there must be a better way...)

Comment: Lisp-like languages are different from each other. They have different object systems, etc. This question is really about Javascript: how to implement a Java design pattern (Dependency Injection) in Javascript. I'm removing the off-topic tags [clojure] [lisp] and [scheme].

Comment: This is not about javascript. Javascript just happens to be the way I am familiar with in order to express the problem. I am interested in the ways the lisp languages deal with the problem, so I would most appreciate if you put the tags back in. Feel free to rephrase the question in a way that makes sense for Lisp, Clojure or Scheme.

Answer (score 6):

This is typically done using closures/currying. You pass in your dependencies as parameters. In JS you could do:

```
buildUserGrid = function(dependency){
    return {
        onMustFetch = function(){
            depenency.doSomething();
        },
        doSomethingElse = function(){
            dependency.doSomethingElse();
        }
    }
}

var userGrid = buildUserGrid(ajaxRequest);
userGrid.onMustFetch();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript I don't know why you couldn't use techniques similar to any OO language. A very basic implementation in JS (sorry, I don't know Coffescript)

```
// expects a function 
var UserGrid = function(ajaxService) {
    this.dependencies = ["ajaxService"];
     // will be overwritten by the DI service, but can also be 
     // assigned manually as in java
    this.ajaxService = ajaxService;
};
UserGrid.prototype.onMustFetch=function() {
    var callback = function() { ... }
    this.ajaxService('/fetch/users',{ surname: 'MacGyver' }, callback);
};

var diController = {
    create: function(constr) {
        var obj = new constr();
        // just look at obj.dependencies to see what should be assigned, and map
        // the implemenations as properties of obj. this could be
        // as simple as a switch or a direct mapping of names to object types
        // ... assign implementations to obj
        return obj;
    }
};
```

Create:

```
var userGrid = diController.create(UserGrid);
```

So `diController` does the same thing as your java dependency injector. In java it can just figure out what type of object is needed using reflection. There's not much reflecting to be done in Javascript, so create a convention to tell the system what is needed. In this case I used an array called "dependencies" but you could use any construct you like.

Comment: Yes, I could use a technique as I would use in OO. But my question - and interest - is on how functional languages, particularly lisp languages, manage dependencies. I am aware that maybe this was not clear enough in my question, but read my comment to the question and you'll understand why. Thanks though...

Comment: In that case then I think the initial comment is highly relevant. Or, are you asking how to manage dependencies without, say, the concept of globals or a factory? Why would you want to do this? The tools you have available to create such constructs are very language specific. Without any kind of global construct, then you already answered your own question, you'll be passing stuff around.

Comment: Indeed, the options I get so far are dependency injection, shared globals, factory, or passing stuff around. I was trying to find out what is typically done in Lisp like languages. So, maybe you are right, maybe there is no other answer to my question in the context I am putting it.